# Raspbian - Panel Preferences (Panel Items) via Terminal Commands

Tags: linux, raspbian

I'm trying to figure out how to automate the setup of a raspberry pi 3B / 3B+ from its default settings to my customized needs via a bash file on a flash drive. I'm using the standard desktop version. [Kernel version](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/): 4.19, Version: February 2020

What I cannot find any help with is how to control and change the Panel Preference (i.e. wifi, bluetooth, date & time, cpu usage, etc.) from the terminal. All of the articles I've found show how to complete this task by selecting the taskbar, Selecting "Add / Remove Panel Items", and then manually make the changes. How can this be automated?

For context of what I have automated thus far for the setup, I've added the code below. If there are improvements to be made or if I'm going to narrow of a direction, feel free to point them out.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ensuring there is an internet connection
sensible-browser https://www.google.com

# Update Raspberry Pi software
sudo apt update; sudo apt full-upgrade -y; sudo apt autoremove -y

# Installing Libre Office and auto updates
sudo apt install libreoffice -y; sudo apt install libreoffice -y
sudo apt install unattended-upgrades -y;
echo 'Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern{
    // Fix missing Raspbian sources.
    "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian";
    "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian-Security";
    "origin=Raspbian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Raspbian";
    "origin=Raspberry Pi Foundation,codename=${distro_codename},label=Raspberry Pi Foundation";
};' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-raspbian

# Setting up Panel Applets <<<----------------- Need help here
# [Add cpu monitor usage with percent used]
# [Update clock format from "%r" to "%h %d, %Y | %I:%M %p"]

# Adding Background Pictures
sudo cp -r ./Pictures/. /usr/share/rpd-wallpaper

# Setting Default Background Picture - Visual signal the setup is complete.
pcmanfm --set-wallpaper /usr/share/rpd-wallpaper/OfficalBG.png

# Restarting the system to fully apply changes
reboot
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it took me a while to find the it, but the file I was looking for is called `panel`, located under `~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels`. It also looks like this file should be treated with care as this file controls the taskbar as well as everything on it.

```
# lxpanel <profile> config file. Manually editing is not recommended.
# User preference dialog in lxpanel to adjust config when you can. 

Global {
  ...
}
Plugin {
  ...
}
...
Plugin {
  type=dclock
  Config {
    ClockFmt=%R
    TooltipFmt=%A %x
    ...
  }
}
...
Plugin {
  type=ptbatt
  Config {
  }
}
....
```